# Why is this static java method not thread safe?

Tags: java, static, thread-safety

The following method does not access any shared variable. It is still not thread safe. I am either testing wrong or I am missing something. Please explain.

Method:

```
public static boolean acquireFolderLock(File directoryPath) {
    final String LOCK_FILE_NAME = ".lock";
    boolean isLocked = false;
    if(directoryPath != null && directoryPath.isDirectory()) {
        File lockFile = new File(new StringBuilder(directoryPath.getAbsolutePath()).append(File.separatorChar).append(LOCK_FILE_NAME).toString());
        if(lockFile.exists()) {
            isLocked = false;
        } else {
            try {
                lockFile.createNewFile();
                isLocked = true;
            } catch(IOException ioex) {
                isLocked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isLocked;
}
```

Thread class for Testing

```
class AThread extends Thread {
String name;
public AThread(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    File f = new File("C:\\TEMP\\DIRECTORY");
    System.out.println(name + ": " + Util.acquireFolderLock(f));
}
}
```

And the main method which starts the threads

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        (new AThread("Thread-->" + i)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining that the method is not thread safe?

Comment: I just added a main method and a test thread class

Comment: You may not be sharing variables, but you are sharing state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method checks whether a file exists and later, it creates it. That means one thread could have done the statement `if (lockFile.exists())` (outcome: `false`) when another thread is doing `lockFile.createNewFile();` (and thus, it creates the lock file).

The first thread is now continuing based on incorrect information: it thinks the file does not exist but it has been created already by another thread.

Thread safety is not just about shared variables, it's about shared resources (be it variables, databases, filesystems, network connections, etc).

Answer (score 3):

"Static state" is a term that includes the file system.  Just because no variables are explicitly shared doesn't mean the *filesystem* isn't shared between threads.

Accessing the filesystem, the way you're doing here, is just as bad as accessing a shared variable, and requires the same techniques to make threadsafe.

Comment: Sorry but can you elaborate? Are you saying if I was modifying a local variable, say a String, instead of a File object, this method becomes Thread safe?

Comment: Nope.  It means you have to add the same thread-safety-guaranteeing operations in both cases.

Comment: @LouisWasserman if the argument really is a String, and nothing calls "external data" then the method would be thread safe as all the variable would be local and the parameter immutable. But admittedly that's many ifs ;)

Comment: If it's a local variable, then there definitely aren't concerns.  If it's a shared variable, there are concerns.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Any article, blog, tutorial you can point to which explains this concept. I have read numerous article but still not clear on the concept between "local shared variable" and "local unshared variable"

Answer (score 0):

According to javadocs for File.createNewFile() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

> Note: this method should not be used for file-locking, as the
>   resulting protocol cannot be made to work reliably. The FileLock
>   facility should be used instead.

So you should be using the java.nio.channels.FileLock, which is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

you are meant to check the return value of lockFile.createNewFile() and you don't need to check lockFile.exists()

```
true if the named file does not exist and was successfully created; false if the named file already exists
```

Also, depending on your use-case nio FileLock might be more unreliable than using createNewFile. i think nio FileLock is broken over NFS. I'm not sure what the javadocs mean by unreliable, but one issue with createNewFile is that when you crash you leave the lock. Though, this can be a feature rather than a bug depending on your use case.

Comment: It is locks that are broken over NFS, not just Java locks.